# SVG make dash line solid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a SVG element that I'm animating via JS and CSS; the SVG is imported from Illustrator. My animation runs nicely so this is more of a SVG (and possibly CSS) question.

There's a small part of the SVG that has some dashed lines; the goal is to have regular solid lines everywhere. Ideally, I would like to achieve this via CSS alone but if altering the SVG element is the only option, then so be it:

[image: svg with dashed lines]

One of the dashed lines:

`<line xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="st10" x1="538.7" y1="147.6" x2="633.9" y2="104.3"/>`

and the st10 class:

`.st10{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-dasharray:2.9444,2.9444;}`

CodePen link: https://codepen.io/sonofkyuss2401/pen/mqQJra

Comment: @RobertLongson yes, that does it if it's static, however in order to animate it, I need to have 'stroke-dasharray' (see my codepen) unless there's another way to achieve that self-draw animation effect that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @RobertLongson I specified I'm animating the SVG and I provided a link to the animation in my question. Anyways, your comment is the actual answer; if I remove the stroke-dasharray property in the class, it turns into a solid line and I can animate it afterwards. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertLongson can you post your comment as an answer so I can choose it as the answer for the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the stroke-dasharray property from the st10 class. The line will then be solid and you can animate it as you wish.